# constructing a php class from a hierarching directory?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got a model that I need to load from;

```
__DIR__.'/../models/api_model.php'
```

however, it needs to be constructed fully - so require_once / include_once isn't giving me access to the functions I need to call. Running a quick include_once just throws back an "undefined function" error when attempting to access this. I would hazard a guess that it's because the old model system I'm working on is based around codeigniter, but this new section is not.

I've attempted to get around this with;

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/../models/api_model.php');
$api_model = new Api_model();
```

However, php seems to be looking for the Api_model class under the current folder, rather than following the hierarchy in the include_once - returning with a "class not found" error.

Is there any way to construct the Api_model class, with it being in a hierarching folder?

Comment: If you are trying to include it from outside CI app, try with absolute path i.e. /var/www/html/project or whatever it is. If you are trying from code within controller, why don't you use CI loading models way. Also, set your model name to first capital if version 3.0 is in case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `APPPATH` globaly defined varible in CI for considering **PATH** for model, and make sure that your model folder has necessary permissions.

Comment: what are your namespaces like?